# Custom app theme is not applied

Tags: android

I created this custom app theme called `Charcoal` in my `styles.xml` file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <!-- custom -->
    <style name="Charcoal" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/charcoalBackground</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/charcoalPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/charcoalPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/gold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here are my colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="gold">#FFD700</color>
    <color name="charcoalBackground">#272727</color>
    <color name="charcoalPrimary">#595858</color>
    <color name="charcoalPrimaryDark">#3a3a3a</color>

</resources>
```

And then I applied the custom theme `Charcoal` to my app in the manifest.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Charcoal">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When I run the app in the emulator the theme appears to be `AppTheme` and not `Charcoal`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because you override it on your activity.          `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">`  If you want to make it Charcoal and NoActionBar, you need to make a single theme that does both.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have placed `android:theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` inside the activity of your manifest which overrides the theme of the application. So remove that line.